# Installed SDKs not found in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin

I have `installed Android SDK from 2.1 to 4.0` and i have worked with Android Projects. But now all the projects throwing exception like `sdk not found`... While checking SDK wizard, nothing SDK is installed. Am i deleted any files?

After Installed SDK:
[image]

But now Except tools no sdk is present

Comment: Make sure you have the proper path configured in Eclipse Window->Preferences->Android. I wonder if you may have two copies installed.

Comment: screenshot you posted it seems you need to update your sdk tools and platform tools

Comment: @Akki: I don't think just because it's outdated it would give this kind of problem. I mean, I saw the R20 update for a few days and kept using it normally until I decided to update...

Comment: @DavidCesarino just yesterday i faced same problem in my case it was showing error tools folder is missing.we have to take extra care when we are updating to ADT 20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restart your IDE then go to preferences and make search for SDk folder (i think that must be in Eclipse folder) set SDk path it will work ..

I think it happens with you because you do not specify you SDK path in preferences -> Android

hope this explanation works for you..